# How to locate exact text on xpath element?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, xpath, beautifulsoup

I am trying to locate the xpath that matches the exact text "Manufacturer" but it is not working.

I cannot use "contains" as there is another xpath element that has text "Discontinued by Manufacturer" in it.
I need a solution where I can use the same thing on other urls which sometimes doesn't have other elements containing the text "Manufacturer" like "Discontinued by Manufacturer" and has only just the "Manufacturer"

The url is [https://www.amazon.com/BEAKEY-Foundation-Blending-Flawless-Multi-colored/dp/B01F36JEXE/ref=sr_1_22?dchild=1&keywords=cosmetics&qid=1625014752&sr=8-22](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01F36JEXE)
if anyone needs a reference

here is what I'm seeing when I try to search for "Manufacturer"
[image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5fIn.png)

Comment: You definitely can use "contains text" as  I suggested until it will be some other element containing this text on the page and that unwanted element is last.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 4 Manufacturer on that page.

you can try this xpath :

```
(//ul[contains(@class, 'a-unordered-list')]/descendant::span[@class='a-text-bold'])[1]
```

to match

```
Is Discontinued By Manufacturer ‏ : ‎ No
```

and

```
(//ul[contains(@class, 'a-unordered-list')]/descendant::span[@class='a-text-bold'])[5]
```

to match :

```
Manufacturer ‏ : ‎ BEAKEY
```

Comment: I don't think using [1] or [5] is right for me as I need to do this for other urls and this one just happens to have two elements that contains the word "Manufacturer" while other urls have just one "Manufacturer"

Comment: there are all under, Ul > LI > span > span. I can tell you it would work. Do not say it will not work until you try first. If you see above I have not used Manufacturer word at all in xpath. first xpath represent the ` Is Discontinued By Manufacturer ‏ : ‎ No` while second one represent the `Manufacturer ‏ : ‎ BEAKEY`

Comment: Do you think, `UPC ` would always be there in different page  ? we can construct an xpath based on UPC to locate Manufacturer

Answer (score 1):

Since there are 2 span elements with text "Manufacturer" this should fit there:

```
"(//span[contains(text(),'Manufacturer')])[last()]"
```

Comment: this won't do for me as when I go to a different url, there is no other element with "Manufacturer" and I would have to call on "(//span[contains(text(),'Manufacturer')])[1]" not [2] on that different url

Comment: I have updated the locator. This will work for single element as well

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match the content of a text node or element exactly, use the "=" operator, not `contains()`.

It's a common XPath mistake to use `contains()` in place of "=". In fact, it's a common mistake to guess what a function does from its name, rather than reading the spec.